# Best way to use PHP to re-populate selected option value after a failed form submission?

Tags: php, forms

I have this form with 10 dropdown selections to choose from and a final checkbox disclaimer at the bottom.

So for example if the user selected all 10 answers and forgets to check the disclaimer box at the bottom and clicks submit, the form will come back with an error message that they didn't agree to the disclaimer but all the answers they had previously selected are gone and they would have to re-do that.  I am trying to find a best practice way to handle this without repeating so much code...

What I have it works but it is crazy redundant especially if I will have 100 questions.

```
<select name="question1" id="question1">
    <?php if ($question[0] == '0') {
        $first = 'selected="selected"';
        $second = '';
        $third = '';
        $fourth = '';
    } elseif ($question[0] == '1') {
        $first = '';
        $second = 'selected="selected"';
        $third = '';
        $fourth = '';
    } elseif ($question[0] == '2') {
        $first = '';
        $second = '';
        $third = 'selected="selected"';
        $forth = '';
    } elseif ($question[0] == '3') {
        $first = '';
        $second = '';
        $third = '';
        $forth = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    ?>
    <option value="0" <?php echo $first; ?>>Answer 1</option>
    <option value="1" <?php echo $second; ?>>Answer 2</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo $third; ?>>Answer 3</option>
    <option value="3" <?php echo $fourth; ?>>Answer 4</option>
</select>
```

This is only for 1 question so you can imagine I would have to repeat that for all questions.  There must be a better way to do this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<option value="0" <?= ($question[0] == 0 ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Answer 1</option>
<option value="1" <?= ($question[0] == 1 ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Answer 1</option>
<option value="2" <?= ($question[0] == 2 ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Answer 1</option>
<option value="3" <?= ($question[0] == 3 ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Answer 1</option>
```

Is *usually* how it's done.

Comment: He still have to this 10 * 4 times. However, I see no better solution. +1

Comment: Indeed, but it's also dependent on how refactored the form generation is. I usually have a more elegant way of displaying/rendering a form than the above, so iterating over answers and checking for a selected answer is easier

Comment: @Rick: Yes, given circumstances. You _could_ use javascript and set `selectElement.value = '<?= $question[0]; ?>'` but no need to use JS for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no elegant solution. I tend to use conditional statements, such as;

```
<option value="0" <?=($question[0] == 0 ? ' selected' : '')?>>Answer 1</option>
```

Comment: He still have to this 10 * 4 times

Comment: You wouldn't be typing these things out manually, just write a loop to echo out all the selects and options!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
$array_existing_values = array(3,5);
$array_options = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach(array_options as $value)
{
    $sel = null;
    if (in_array($array_existing_values,$array_options)
    {
         $sel = ' selected ';
    }
    $html_options .= "<option value='$value' $sel>$value</option>";
}
```

Add validation to season.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Have `$questions` hold all the questions for the user like this:

```
$questions = array(
    // The first question
    array(
       'question' => 'The 1st question?'
       'answers' => array(
           'answer 1',
           'answer 2',
           'answer 3',
           'answer 4',
       )
    ),
    // The second question
    array(
        ...
    ),
    // etc
);
```

And `$answer` contains all the answers from the user like this:

```
$answer = array(1, 2, 3, 2, ... );
```

Then you can redraw all your questions like this:

```
foreach ($questions as $index => $question)
{
    echo "<p>" . $question['question'] ."</p>\n";
    echo "<select name='question" . $index . "' id='question" . $index . "'>\n";
    foreach ($question['answers'] as $value => $answer)
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $value . "' " . ($value == $answer[$index] ? "selected='true'" : "") . ">" . $answer . "</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```